# How to make Android lifecycle aware component get called on using Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-architecture-components

I have a [lifecycle aware component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html) that is being called from an Activity. It works fine in `debug` mode. But when minified (Proguard), the lifecyle component doesn't seem to be called. What is the rule to add to `proguard-rules.pro`?

After much hassle, I've gotten the answer. Please check below. [Original Tweet](https://twitter.com/rakshakhegde/status/875107392198856706)

Comment: If you are trying to post a FAQ-style entry, please [follow the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Change your question to be an actual question, for which your answer is the answer. Do not just link to a tweet.

Comment: Alright guys, I've made the changes. I kindly request you to reconsider it.

Answer (score 0):

`-keep` the Lifecycle aware component and also the `Lifecycle.Event` annotations in your `proguard-rules.pro` file. [Original Tweet](https://twitter.com/rakshakhegde/status/875107392198856706)

```
-keep public class android.arch.lifecycle.** {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent public *;
}
```